# Java Newbie having trouble understanding some `new` syntax

Tags: java, new-operator

I'm a relative newbie to Java. I program in other languages and I use Java mainly when I need to use third party libraries that are only available as Java. As such, I have only very basic understanding of the language. But usually this is enough to get my business done.

Today I ran into a problem that is so basic I'm having trouble Googling it or looking it up. In the following code snipit I don't understand the `new GSRadContext` line at all:

```
GSRBristowCampbellStrategy algo = new GSRBristowCampbellStrategy();
RadData rd = new RadData();

... 

GSRadContext gsr = new GSRadContext( (IAGSRadStrategy) algo);
gsr.evaluate(rd);
```

In my limited Java experience I've never seen this type of syntax inside of a `new object()` call before. Can you explain to me what's going on with the `(IAGSRadStrategy)` bit?

Thanks for contributing to my education.

Comment: One day people will use generics appropriately, and casting will be considered really esoteric.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This bit:

```
(IAGSRadStrategy) algo
```

is completely separate from the constructor. If it helps, you can think of the second bit of code as:

```
IAGSRadStrategy tmp = (IAGSRadStrategy) algo;
GSRadContext gsr = new GSRadContext(tmp);
gsr.evaluate(rd);
```

It's just a casting expression. Without knowing the type hierarchy involved, it's tricky to know exactly why it's being used here, but *normally* a cast is to basically tell the compiler, "You only know about this expression as Foo, but *I* know it's a Bar... so please check it for me at execution time, and then treat the value as a Bar for the result of this expression."

Comment: makes perfect sense. I know so little Java I didn't recognize a cast when I saw it. Now I know!

Comment: Further, it means the GSRadContext() method is expecting a parameter of type IAGSRadStrategy, and you are explicitly casting the algo variable to that type. It looks like "algo" is something that implements the IAGSRadStrategy interface.

Answer (score 1):

`algo`, a reference to a `GSRBristowCampbellStrategy` is being cast as a `IAGSRadStrategy` and passed to the `GSRadContext` constructor.

Gratuitous Wikipedia link:

[Type Conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion)

Answer (score 1):

This `GSRadContext` class has a constructor which takes a `IAGSRadStrategy` type of object as argument. The `algo` instance is a sub-type of IAGSRadStrategy, that's why it is being type-casted into that type.